# How to take a string as an input in a text field and store it in a variable but show another string in the text field in java netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

So what I want to do is that, user enters the string which gets stored in a variable but, there is the catch, as user enters the string simultaneously another string should be displayed in the text field, for example, suppose user wants to enter the string "netbeans" and the other string (which I want to display instead of "netbeans") is "program". So when user enters "n", "p" should be displayed in the text field and "n" should be stored in a variable, similarly when "e" is entered "r" should be displayed and the "e" should be added to "n" to make "ne" and so on.

Comment: So you would like to replace one letter by the other?

Comment: Add a listener on the text field for a key press, and then update the other display field, and update any variable desired. There are too many use cases here to give much more, I think. What if the Strings are different length? What if a character that is not in the first String is entered?

Comment: What do you intend by that? Some kind of Caesar cipher (this is for single letters only)? From point of view of the user, this might be very irritating, possibly better approach to have an input field and a separate output field?

Answer (score 0):

> So when user enters "n", "p" should be displayed in the text field and "n" should be stored in a variable,

You can use a `DocumentFilter`. This will allow you to access each character as it is typed and before it is added to the `Document`. So this will allow you to translate each character and then append the character to another variable.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information and examples.